# CSS media queries: identifying handheld devices

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, handheld

Am looking for suggestions to accurately select for the majority of handheld devices via media queries. Maybe in the olden days `device-width` would have sufficed but with modern phones having screen resolutions matching desktops this no longer works.

Essentially I want to select for physical screen size, say less than 6 inches wide. And preferably without using javascript.

Any common media query patterns for this?